# Hbase shell: how to scan rows based on specific multiple column values

Tags: hbase

New to Hbase, don't have hive or impala configured. :-(
Now wanted to scan rows of a table based on multiple column values
let say having Table A with 4 columns aa, ab, ac, ad. I wanted all rows of the table which satisfied the values condition of column ab & ad.

And other query is how to query on multiple tables assuming have external key are presents in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate your scenarios: One HBase table named **A**, One Column Family **CF1** and within it there are four column qualifiers i.e. **aa, ab, ac, ad**

Your requirement is to get rows which meet the two column qualifiers ab & ad  conditions

> The way for this implementation is to go with SingleColumnValueFilter.
>   Create filter list, as many as you want (two filter list in your case)
>   And add filters in the dependent order

If you have two different column families (A & B), then 
Scan 'A' , {COLUMNS => ['A:aa' , 'B:ab']}

In your second question, what do you mean by external key? If you are referring to a unique composite key identifier then explore secondary Index.

Answer (score 0):

For scanning rows on multiple columns in single hbase table you can use Hbase Api and the following java code might solve your problem.

```
 SingleColumnValueFilter f1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("0"), Bytes.toBytes("EMP_KEY"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(500));
  SingleColumnValueFilter f2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("0"), Bytes.toBytes("DEPT_KEY"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(204));

  FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL); //could be FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL instead
  filterList.addFilter(f1);
  filterList.addFilter(f2);

  Scan scan = new Scan();
  scan.setFilter(filterList);
```